# NBTF Experimental Weapons (Roblox)

Tags: roblox, nuclear-bomb-testing-facility

Recently I found the NBTF experimental weapons (near the announcement system) and I'm not able to use them. (I know why) I wasn't originally planning to get the Warlord and/or Overseer, but I may get them because of the Experimental Weapons. Anybody have gameplay footage of the experimental weapons, or stats (damage,etc.) ?